# Need help in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the scenario for which we have to come up with Oracle query. Please let us know if you can help us with SQL query here.

We have to fetch data based on 3 fields in a single table.

```
Table name: CS_01
Field names:
ID_74
EFF_DATE
ID_TYPE
```

Conditions are as below :

1. Record should be selected based on max(EFF_DATE).
2. If two records have the same ID_74, same EFF_DATE but different ID_TYPE then ID_TYPE should be selected based on below ranking.

   ```
   WHEN 'DLIC' THEN 1 
   WHEN 'CAND' THEN 1 
   WHEN 'STID' THEN 1 
   WHEN 'PASP' THEN 2 
   WHEN 'UPAS' THEN 2 
   WHEN 'MLID' THEN 3 
   WHEN 'GUAT' THEN 4 
   WHEN 'MXCN' THEN 4 
   WHEN 'RAID' THEN 4 
   WHEN 'VISA' THEN 4 
   WHEN 'FORN' THEN 5 
   ELSE             6
   ```

Ex: If we have below two records-  then first record should be selected

```
ID_74   EFF_DATE    ID_TYPE ID_OCCUR    Amount
10  2-Oct-15    DLIC    1   100
10  2-Oct-15    VISA    1   120
```

3. If all 3 fields ( ID_74, EFF_DATE, ID_TYPE) are same then record appearing at top should be selected.

Sample data:

```
ID_74   EFF_DATE    ID_TYPE ID_OCCUR    Amount
11  3-Oct-15    PASP    1   25
11  2-Sep-15    DLIC    1   35
10  2-Oct-15    VISA    1   120
10  2-Oct-15    DLIC    1   100
9   8-Sep-15    FORN    1   23
9   8-Sep-15    FORN    1   50
```

Scenario1 : For ID 11 first record should be selected.

Scenario2 : For ID 10 second record should be selected.

Scenario3 : For ID 9 First record should be selected.

Can you please help in SQL query. We tried dense_rank() but ranking is not assigned as per our requirement.

Comment: Maybe SO should be coding service ;)

Comment: Please post the SQL query you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Despite the names `RANK` and `DENSE_RANK`, you'd most often use `ROW_NUMBER` for ranking :-)

```
select 
  id_74, eff_date, id_type, id_occur, amount
from
(
  select 
    id_74, eff_date, id_type, id_occur, amount,
    row_number() over (partition by id_74 order by <your order here>) as rn
  from mytable
)
where rn = 1;
```

So all you have to do is replace "<your order here>" with your sort order which orders your records from best to worst. Thus the best record per id_74 get's rn = 1, and only those you keep in the outer query.